# xlarge, xxlarge breakpoints not working in Foundation 6

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I want to combine responsive classes, something like `<div class="cell large-1 xlarge-3 xxlarge-6">`.

I am using Foundation 6.6.3, I have already changed my settings.scss with `$breakpoint-classes: (small medium large xlarge xxlarge);`

But I can't still get the expected behavior, Does anybody know what do I need in order to make it work?

Comment: Have you defined the breakpoints ? https://get.foundation/sites/docs/media-queries.html#changing-the-breakpoints

Comment: Yes, I defined them previously, then add them to the breakpoint-classes, but they are not working